# Is it right to answer home work questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A Consolidated Homework Policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/a-consolidated-homework-policy)

Generally I see questions from students that are part of their homework for a particular course (say probability theory, random processes, measure theory, etc.). Some users answer those questions providing a complete solution and some just provide hints. Is there a general guideline on this? In my view homework questions should be answered via hints and that's it. (Of course, many questions gets asked that are not tagged as homework, but I think we all know they are)

Comment: If you search a bit here on meta you will find *several* old questions about this subject. Maybe you can find what you want there?

Comment: There is even a tag to mark those meta questions!